# Coproducts in dagger categories

Tags: category-theory, dagger-categories

I am a beginner with category theory. I have defined a category that seems like it might be useful for me. (The details don't matter here.) It turns out that this category has a [product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)), and it also turns out that this category is a [dagger category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dagger+category), in that for every morphism $f:A\to B$ there is a morphism $f:B\to A$, and vice versa.

From these two properties it seems to follow that my category has a [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct), since I can just reverse all the arrows in the definition of the product to get the definition of a coproduct. However, while the product is nice and easy to interpret the coproduct seems a bit strange and mysterious.

It seems like the dagger property might make the coproduct relate to the product in some simple, convenient way that would make its interpretation obvious. However, I haven't yet found much information about how products and coproducts behave, in general, in dagger categories. Are there general results on this that could help with understanding my specific case?

Comment: From your description, it looks like what you have is a dagger category (https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/dagger+category).

Comment: Thank you, yes, that's exactly what I have. I'll read that page and see if this needs updating.

Comment: I've updated the terminology. (I'm not currently sure whether "dagger category" and "self-dual category" mean the same thing, but "dagger category" definitely applies to what I have.)

Comment: Not every self-dual category is a dagger category, but dagger categories are definitely self-dual.

Answer (score 1):

In a dagger category, coproducts *are* products: applying $\dagger$ to a limit cone defining the product gives the colimit cone defining the coproduct.

In fact, you can check directly that the product satisfies the formula defining the coproduct: there is a natural bijection

$$ \hom(X \times Y, Z) \cong \hom(X, Z) \times \hom(Y, Z) $$

The forward and backwards directions are

- $f \mapsto (f \pi_0^\dagger, f \pi_1^\dagger) $
- $(g, h) \mapsto \langle g^\dagger, h^\dagger \rangle ^\dagger$

where $\pi_0 : X \times Y \to X$ (et al), and for $u : Z \to X$ and $v : Z \to Y$, I use $\langle u, v \rangle$ to denote the corresponding map $Z \to X \times Y$.